# Does the premium of an option of a certain strike price increase at a slower rate from OTM to ITM as gamma affects delta?

Tags: stocks, trading, options, stock-valuation, derivatives

I buy an OTM strike
the price converge towards the selected strike price
premium increase at a rate of delta
does the rate of the increase slow down due to gamma?

Comment: This might be more at home n the Quants discussion than here. When people start using Greek letters to describe their investment idea, it's all Greek to me.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume constant volatility, gamma increases as the stock gets closer to the strike price. Thus, delta is increasing at a faster rate as the stock reaches closer to ITM because gamma is the derivative of delta. As the stock gets deeper ITM, the gamma will slow down as delta reaches 1 or -1 (depends if a call or a put). Thus, the value of the option will change depending upon the level of the delta. I am ignoring volatility and time for this description.

See this diagram from Investopedia:
[Gamma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcoJ9.gif)